# Where can I download older version of Raspberry Pi Imager

Tags: pi-3, pi-4

Appreciate any help. 
I am looking to download older version of Raspberry Pi Imager. The reason is I need to download ubuntu 16.04 arm64 for Pi 3B and Pi4B. The latest imager dooes not show thsese releases in the list when we open the tool. I downloaded ubuntu 16.04 arm64 for Pi 3 and Pi4 from ubuntu site and imaged to sd card and does not work. I think if i download using pi imager will work.

Thanks for any inputs.

Comment: Probable cause is the image size: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/111236/5538

Comment: Download the images separately and use [balenaEtcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash them.  *NB:* I haven't tried this particular combination, but Etcher hasn't failed me yet.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but already used Etcher, but did not boot my Pi3B and Pi4B..not sure..

Comment: I just tried this also, but Pi3B does not boot ?  dd if=ubuntu-16.04.4-server-arm64.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=100M

Answer (score 2):

To download previous versions of Raspberry Pi Imager (starting from v1.2), check out the Releases page on the rpi_imager GitHub site:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-imager/releases

Click the "assets" tab to see the available downloads.

Answer (score 1):

The wrong part is

dd if=ubuntu-16.04.4-server-arm64.iso of=/dev/**sdb1** bs=100M

You are trying to flash a device image into a *partition*. You need to flash it to the *block device* itself, i.e. `/dev/sdb`.

The same issue is possible in Windows, but the terminology will change from one program to another. In some programs partitions are called disks.

Comment: thanks, with this I am getting error:     dd if=ubuntu-16.04.4-server-arm64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=100M
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Permission denied

Comment: Run it as root. And make sure you've selected the right device, there will be no second warning before the device is overwritten.

Comment: Thank you, i am able to flash now after running as root, but the Pi does not boot??  dd if=ubuntu-16.04.4-server-arm64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=100M